# How to read very long numbers in a file in c

Tags: c, file, scanf, long-integer

I have to collect very long numbers from a file (like number 20414363521583006011), and I can't find how... I thought about using fscanf() and the type long long but it isnt enough... It just returns -1.

Comment: Just read them in as strings unless you need to do computation on them. If you need to compute you need a "bignum" library.

Comment: @hazelnut Are the numbers integers only?

Comment: I will look for bignum librariez then, thank you

Comment: yes they are only integers

Comment: Please describe what you want to do with the "numbers". That will determine how the data should be best read and stored.

Answer (score 0):

Use GMP, the GNU Multi-Precision library, which includes a [`gmp_scanf`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input-Strings.html#Formatted-Input-Strings) supporting arbitrary precision integers, and is widely supported and available on most systems.

Note that you will also have to use it for any subsequent operations on your large integers (of type `mpz_t`), such as printing them as well as arithmetic, but it's pretty easy to use.

(I'm on my phone right now otherwise I would give you a usage example, but the docs contain many examples as well).